# Convert the date to format yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.S'Z' in xslt2.0

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have the input date format as `2014-04-14T00:00:00-05:00` and would like to convert to a format `2014-04-14T00:00:00.5Z` (i.e., yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.S'Z').

I am able to do this in java using SimpleDateFormat class but i need to do the same using XSLT2.0.

Options Tried: `format-dateTime($dt, '[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]T[H01]:[m01]:[s01].[f001]Z')`

But this option result was `2014-04-14T00:00:00.000Z` which is supposed to be `2014-04-14T00:00:00.5Z` (expected output).

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The date you've given doesn't have fractional seconds (which is what [f001] is looking for in your function). It has a time zone of -05:00 (Eastern Standard Time). See the description of xs:dateTime here: http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime

ETA: I don't think the format you want is going to be possible using just an XSL date format function, as you're losing the positive/negative before the time zone offset. Something like this will get you closer:

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-dateTime($dt, '[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]T[H01]:[m01]:[s01].[z]Z')"/>
```

returns:
    2014-04-14T00:00:00.GMT-5Z

You could use a simple string function to strip out 'GMT-'. You may want to be careful, though, if you will ever have need to convert this date back, or into another format.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am expecting the time zone -05:00 to be represented as 5Z in the output. i.e., '2014-04-14T00:00:00.5Z'. Let's say if the input is '2012-11-01T00:00:00-06:00' then the expected output is '2014-04-14T00:00:00.6Z'.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I was trying to avoid the string operations and it looks like there is no option for my expected output i guess.

Answer (score 0):

Your target format

2014-04-14T00:00:00.5Z

(in which 5Z represents the timezone -05:00) is completely non-standard, and highly undesirable since it's likely to be misread as meaning "half a second past midnight, UTC". So it's not surprising that it should be a bit tricky to generate. If you're forced to use this format for some reason, then you're going to have to generate the timezone part manually, which you can do by starting with `timezone-from-dateTime($x) div xs:dayTimeDuration('PT1H')`.